# Express $\sin\frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ with $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I've been trying with no success expressing this functions.

a) $\sin\frac{\pi}{8}$ with $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$

b) $\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ with $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$

I've tried formula of the double angle ($\sin$ and $\cos$) and the ecuation $\cos^2X+\sin^2X=1$.

Can anyone point what to use or where to start?

I appreciate it, thanks.

---

UPDATE

I think this is achived with the half formula as njguliyev and nbubis said.

$$\sin\frac{\pi}{8} = \sin(\frac{1}{2} * \frac{\pi}{4}) = \pm\sqrt\frac{1-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}$$

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{8} = \cos(\frac{1}{2} * \frac{\pi}{4}) = \pm\sqrt\frac{1+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}$$

Comment: $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

You my want to take a look at the [half angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-AngleFormulas.html).

Answer (score 1):

I mean just use the trig identities: $$\cos \frac{ PI }{4} = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \frac{ PI}{8} $$